# Как правильно запускать докер-контейнер на VDS?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vps, vds

Собрал докер-контейнер, и запускаю на VDS через:

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

Соответственно, при заходе на страницы - все работает, но стоит нажать Ctr+C, то контейнер останавливается и соответственно не работает уже. Можно конечно, взять закрыть окно консоли и он останется работать, но это же не вариант.

Поэтому как правильно его оставить работать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для запуска контейнеров в фоновом режиме нужно добавить опцию detach

```
sudo docker-compose up --detach
```

или что тоже самое:

```
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/

Для того, чтобы контейнер автоматически запускался при перезапуске системы нужно в `docker-compose.yml` в нужном контейнере указать параметр, отвечающую за политику перезапуска

```
services:
  some_service:
    # ...
    restart: always
```

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

Comment: т.е. не надо прописывать сервис для докера в **/etc/systemd/system**?

Comment: @АлексейБелкин при установке докера - устанавливается сервис `docker`  см: `service --status-all | grep docker`

Comment: @АлексейБелкин либо `systemctl list-units --type=service | grep docker`

Comment: Получается, что этот сервис курирует все контейнеры? И если я захочу еще запустить один контейнер, то он будет также работать в фоновом режиме?

Comment: да. могу еще добавить в ответ опцию политики перезапуска. Чтобы контейнер подымался автоматически при перезапуске системы

Comment: @АлексейБелкин добавил в ответ параметр, отвечающий за политику перезапуска контейнера

Comment: С командой **--restart** не запускается, говорит, что нет такой опции

Comment: @АлексейБелкин сейчас разберемся

Comment: @АлексейБелкин, да виноват. параметр только в docker run можно прокинуть, для  compose  нужно в файле указать - сейчас отпишусь

Comment: @АлексейБелкин, Поправил, добавил. Проверил у себя - работает.

Comment: @АлексейБелкин, если будут вопросы  или проблемы - пишите\\

Comment: @АлексейБелкин, отпишитесь по итогу - все получилось или нет

Comment: Ну параметры **restart: always** у меня на всех образах прописаны)